# C++ - Conditional virtual functions

Tags: c++, class, virtual

My question is, if I have something like

```
class Base {
 ...
 public:
  virtual void func();
}

void Base::func() {
 //Implementation # 1
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
 ...
 public:
  void func();
}

void Derived1::func() {
 //Implementation # 1
}

class Derived2 : public Base {
 ...
 public:
  void func();
}

void Derived2::func()
 //Implementation # 1
}

class Derived3 : public Base {
 ...
 public:
  void func();
}

void Derived3::func() {
 //Implementation # 2
}
```

What I'm trying to do is I want Derived1 and Derived2 to use the implementation of func() that was used in Base, but I want Derived3 to use func() a little differently. The problem is, if I make func() virtual in Base, then both Derived1 and Derived2 will need to implement it differently which I don't want. However, if I don't make it virtual, then all derived classes will have the same implantation for func(). How can I get past this problem?

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. So would I be correct in saying that with public inheritance all of Derived1,2,3 will have access the func() implemented in Base unless they declare it in their own classes, in which case, the new declaration is used.

Comment: That's correct, except that they'd still have access even with private inheritance (though the method wouldn't be visible outside the derived classes), and even when overridden in a derived class, the base method can still be explicitly called if desired.

Comment: Could it be something like the code that follows where you define virtual the function only in Derived1 ?

Comment: @Cameron. Thanks. What syntax would I use to call the Base method even when its been overridden?

Comment: @Q_A: See user1708860 and mman's answers. You prefix the base class name to to specify that you wish to call that specific method, resulting in a non-virtual call to that (otherwise virtual) method.

Answer (score 6):

A virtual function does not *have* to be overridden. `Derived1` and `Derived2` can just not redeclare `func()`.

Only a *pure virtual* function (declared with `= 0`) must be overridden by (non-abstract) derived classes.

Comment: They do not need to do **anything** about it (not sure what you mean by 'redeclare').

Comment: @SergeyA: What's unclear? Seems like a perfectly sensible description.

Comment: @KerrekSB, we usually use the word 'override'. 'Redeclaration' is not something which is specified in standard. And if you literally construct it from standard-defined 'declaration' and 're', you will end up with the wrong thing altogether, because nothing can be declared again in the same translation unit.

Comment: I mean redeclare in the sense they each (re)declare `func` in order to define a different virtual implementation of it for their class.

Comment: @SergeyA: Well, a *declaration* is something well-defined, and we're talking about the declaration of a member in a derived class that's already declared in a base class, so "redeclaration" seems like an appropriate choice of words here. In fact, it's a choice of words that describes just how one would go about not overriding something.

Comment: @Cameron, I suggest avoiding this term.

Comment: @KerrekSB, exactly - see updates to my comment. But you really can't redeclare anything. It is never possible.

Comment: Oh, and latest edit is wrong. pure virtual function can easily have definition. Cameron, I think you need a refresher on declaration and definition.

Comment: I'm going to take a radical stand and not get pulled into a discussion on which term is better :-) I use both in my answer in an attempt to be clear, even to those learning OOP.

Comment: @SergeyA: Ah yes, of course you're right about the pure virtual definition. A favourite for destructors. I do know the difference between a declaration and a definition, by the way -- I often work with C++ parsers all day!

Comment: @Cameron: Even a pure virtual function needn't be overridden. It only needs to be overridden in a *non-abstract* derived class.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I do not see any redeclaration, I see a repetition of the same declaration. Now it's a liguistic thing - if repetition of the same thing (in plain English grammar) is a redeclaration or not. I hate linguistic arguments, and this is exactly why I wanted OP to stop using this word with undefined meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

This will work, but unless you need more work done in the function, @Cameron's answer is the correct one.

You can call the base function from the derived function like so:

```
class Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { /* Do something */ };
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { /* Do something else */ };
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
   virtual void foo() { Base::foo(); /* Do something */ };
};
```

Comment: @SergeyA, He may need to do more things in the function, even though he did not specify that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought to define as virtual func only in derived1 ?

The code that follows works like that ( is that what you intended ? )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X


class Base {

 public:
  void func();
};


void Base::func() {
    printf("Base\n");
}

class Derived1 : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void func();
};

void Derived1::func() { 
    printf("derived1\n"); 
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
 public:
};

class Derived3 : public Base {
 public:
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Base b;
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    Derived3 d3;

    b.func();
    d1.func();
    d2.func();
    d3.func();

    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call inside the func() of Derived1 and Derived2 the Base func() like this

```
Base::func();
```

Derived3 func() can have a different implementation.